# How can I control the duration of toast sounds?

Tags: sound, push-notifications

In our app we're using a custom toast notification sound. This sound is 10 seconds long, but when the toast is received, only 3 seconds of the sound are played.

What setting controls for how long toast notification sounds are played or what options do I have to control this behavior?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a phone system question, or a development question?

Comment: @Drowin: Either would work for me, but I'm interested from the users perspective. I assumed this is an aspect you have no control over development wise.

Comment: There is no way for the phone user to control it. I don't know about the developer side.

Comment: Seems like this might be a universal, built-in maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately neither the dev nor the user can change the maximum duration of a notification sound at the moment. 
You should consider adding a feature request on http://windowsphone.uservoice.com

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Thomas's answer, apps can customise the toast notification sound (see apps such as Skype). So I think it's unlikely you'll be able to change the duration in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use [long-duration toast notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh779727.aspx) to get what you want. (Note, though, that they will only work on WP 8.0). I've never used them, so I'm not sure if this is what you're wanting or not.